# Baidu ECharts2 dynamic chart position based on the legend height

Tags: height, echarts, baidu

I'm using Baidu ECharts2 to visualise a dynamic amount of series (up to 100) as a line chart.
The issue I face is the legend overlaps the graph in case if the series are too many.
[image]

I spent good 2 hours in searching the documentation and reading, but cannot figure out any way to set the graph position (y/y2 top/height).

It seems the chart consists of different elements (legend, toolbox etc), but none of them seems to be the graph itself.

An example I found showcases a fully responsive way to position pie charts, but this is not applicable in my case:
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=doc-example/pie-media

I'd be grateful if someone has more experience with ECharts and can tell me way to move the graph down by y and set a height.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Your best option may be to set the legend type to scroll so it fits on one line.

```
legends.push({
    type: 'scroll',
    show: true,
    data: myData,
    ...
});
```

You may also be able combine Ovilia's and Zain's solutions to move the grid down to leave space for the legend. Unfortunately that would require a way to determine the legend's size before setting the chart's container size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The Scroll works pretty nice. I think it is better than using the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `grid` position to make it.

In [ECharts 2](http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/doc.html#Grid), you may set `grid.y`, `grid.y2`, or `grid.height`.

In [ECharts 3](http://echarts.baidu.com/option.html#grid), you may set `grid.top`, `grid.bottom`, or `grid.height`.